# How to convert this complex SQL Query with Subqueries into LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, translation

How do I convert the following query into a Linq expression?

```
SELECT p.playerid,
       (SELECT SUM(d.runs)
        FROM   deliveries d
               INNER JOIN overs o ON d.overid = o.overid
        WHERE  o.isbatting = 1
               AND o.gameid = 5
               AND d.player_playerid = playerid) AS runsfor,
       (SELECT SUM(d.runs)
        FROM   deliveries d
               INNER JOIN overs o
                 ON d.overid = o.overid
        WHERE  o.isbatting = 0
               AND o.gameid = 5
               AND d.player_playerid = playerid) AS runsagainst,
       ( (SELECT SUM(d.runs)
          FROM   deliveries d
                 INNER JOIN overs o ON d.overid = o.overid
          WHERE  o.isbatting = 1
                 AND o.gameid = 5
                 AND d.player_playerid = playerid) -
         (SELECT SUM(d.runs)
          FROM   deliveries d
                 INNER JOIN overs o ON d.overid = o.overid
          WHERE  o.isbatting = 0
                 AND o.gameid = 5
                 AND d.player_playerid =
                     playerid) ) AS runscontributed
FROM   deliveries d
       INNER JOIN players p ON d.player_playerid = p.playerid
       INNER JOIN overs o   ON d.overid = o.overid
WHERE  o.gameid = 1
GROUP  BY p.playerid
```

The results generated look like:

```
2   13  16  -3
4   -5  18  -23
5   -6  11  -17
7   4   1   3
8   5   7   -2
9   12  17  -5
10  -4  24  -28
12  19  1   18
```

Comment: Which part if the query are you struggling with?

Comment: @Chris - yeah, tell me about it.

Comment: @Magnus - The joins are becoming a problem and I'd rather avoid using several variables and use intersect if I could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start out by simplifying.

```
SELECT d.*, o.*
FROM   deliveries d
INNER JOIN overs o ON d.overid = o.overid
```

```
var joined = from d in deliveries
             join o in overs on d.overid equals o.overid
             select new { d, o };
```

Then simplify some more...

```
SELECT SUM(d.runs)
FROM   deliveries d
INNER JOIN overs o ON d.overid = o.overid
WHERE  o.isbatting = 1
       AND o.gameid = 5
       AND d.player_playerid = playerid
```

```
(from j in joined
 where j.o.isBatting 
 && j.o.gameId == 5 
 && j.d.player.playerId == playerId
 select j.d.runs).Sum();
```

Lather, rinse, repeat:

```
var joined = from d in deliveries
             join players p on d.player_playerid equals p.playerid
             join o in overs on d.overid equals o.overid;
             where j.o.gameid = 1
             select new { p, d, o };

var _runsfor = from j in joined
               where j.o.isBatting 
               && j.o.gameId == 5 
               && j.d.player.playerId == some_player_id
               select j;

var ungrouped = from j in joined
                select new 
                {
                    playerId = j.p.playerid,
                    runsFor = _runsfor.Where(r => r.p.playerId == j.p.playerId)
                                      .Sum(jn => jn.d.runs),
                    runsAgainst = //etc...
                };      

var grouped = from u in ungrouped 
              group new { u.runsFor, u.runsAgainst, /* etc... */ }
              by u.playerId into player
              select player;
```

I'm not certain this will do what you want, but it should give you a jumping off point.

Don't use this code directly; I wrote it freehand, and I'm not sure it will work the first time without some tweaking. The real point here is to simplify. Break your SQL query into smaller groups and write the LINQ for those. Then write some more LINQ to tie it all together. The ability to do that is one of the best things about LINQ.

Comment: This is good enough for me. I'll have a crack at it when I'm back at my computer and edit as (if) required. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler - Glad to help. Might want to pay special attention to the `ungrouped` query, including the inner `Where`; I don't have your schema in front of me, so I couldn't test as I went.

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler - Edit: Took my own advice and simplified; I've split off `runsfor` from `ungrouped`'s inner logic. Cheers.